# Including another plugin with mine

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is it considered bad practice to include a plugin from another source (MIT licensed) with your own zipped plugin files (or even on github)?

**To elaborate**: I wanted to include another plugin as part of my plugin package, not my site, but the github file or zip that I provide to others when they grab my plugin. It's not a required plugin to make my plugin work, but it enhances certain portions of it. And of course I will give credit to the author and provide a link to their site when I document the instructions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking? Are you asking if it's okay to include other 3rd-party plugins on your site? -- if that's the question that I'd say it's fine, so long as you know that the plugin is built well and doesn't mess with globals/natives.

Comment: @J-P - I've edited my question to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recomend the use of a third party plugin in combination whith your own plugin, i see no problem whith including it in the download, as long as you give credit where it's due.

i personally think it's rather convientient when i can download from a single source, but i would reccomend you to also link to the 3rd party plugin for documentation and to give credit.

this however is my personal opinion, and there may be legal implications aswell. the safest route to take would probably be to just ask the developer of the third party plugin.